# Right invariant Killing fields of Right invariant Riemanian metrics

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups

Can there exist a right invariant killing field of a right invariant (but not bi-invariant)  Riemannian metric on a Lie group?

I am especially interested in the case of $SU(N)$ with a metric of the form (at the identity):
$g(x,y) = \frac{1}{\lambda} B(x,y) + \frac{1}{\lambda^2} B(x,w)B(y,w)$ where $w$ is an arbitrary given vector in $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ s.t. B(w,w) < 1 and B is the Killing form (taken to be positive definite).

Comment: The answer to your question is trivially _yes_, because a bi-invariant metric is right-invariant.

Comment: I should have clarified, right invariant but not bi-invariant. Sorry for the confusion. $B$ is bi-invariant but $w$ is only right invariant. As far as I know such a metric cannot be bi-invariant as $w$ would need to be bi-invariant and there are no such vector fields on $SU(n)$.

Comment: Indeed.  But I’m just pointing out, perhaps unhelpfully, that your first question _as written_ has a trivial answer.  Hence, perhaps you’d like to ask a more precise question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A right invariant Riemannian metric is invariant und all right translations. A left invariant vector field has a flow consisting of right translations (by $\exp(tX)$).
Thus each left invariant field is a Killing field. A right invariant field $R_X$ is Killing if and only if $S^2(\text{ad}_X)^*g_{e}=0$.

Comment: I am aware that all left invariant vector fields are killing. I have arrived at the equation $g([a,w], a+w) = 0$ $\forall a \in \mathfrak{su}(n)$ as a condition for the specific case I mentioned. Is this a special case of your equation above?

Answer (score 2):

There is an obvious right-invariant vector field which leaves that metric invariant: the one which extends $w$.  As Peter Michor mentions in his answer, the condition for a right-invariant vector field to be Killing is that it should preserve the inner product at the identity.  In your example, and letting $b = \lambda^{-1} B$, and using the ad-invariance of the Killing form,
$$ (\operatorname{ad}_z^* g)(x,y) = - b(x,[z,w])b(y,w) - b(x,w)b(y,[z,w]) $$
which vanishes for $z = w$.

Comment: Would it be sufficient to solve $(ad^*_z g)(x,x) = 0$ rather than introducing y also?

Comment: Sure, you can recover the general case by polarisation as usual.

Comment: Ok, thanks. That is really helpful. Am I right in thinking that the proof in your answer would be correct for arbitrary right invariant $b$ rather than just the killing form? I mean for a metric of the form in the original question but where $B$ is an arbitrary right invariant metric?

Comment: Yes, all I used was the ad-invariance of $b$.